# How can I generate JSON-LD in a standalone java project?

Tags: java, rdf, semantic-web, json-ld

I have a java standalone application which generates triplets for RDF. I want to convert  them to JSON-LD. This is not a web based system. How can I do it? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. JSON-LD Java API you mentioned, has pom.xml file. Do you think, I have to add maven for this project?
I cannot use apache since this is not web based system.

Comment: You don't have to use Maven, but the project has all it's dependencies defined via Maven. If you don't want to use Maven in your project, you have to at least checkout the project and build a Jar file with Maven shade plugin - this Jar file will then contain all dependencies

Comment: *"I cannot use apache since this is not web based system"* -> that statement doesn't make sense. Both, Apache Jena and RDF4J are pure Java APIs for handling RDF. I don't understand what you mean by "web based system"

Comment: I don't know much things about these. thank you for your advises. I will search for shade plugin. 
The project I am developing does not use Apache. That's why I thought I can not use Apache Jena.

Comment: "Apache" is the name of the foundation and the name of a specific project it manages. Projects hosted and maintained by the foundation are named "Apache X", does not mean they expose anything on the web. Apache Jena, for example, is just a plain library, nothing to do with a web server.